# Linear Programming Free Variables

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

I am using a book called *Introduction to Operations Research*.

I'm not sure how to deal with free variables that are not constrained i.e. they could be positive or negative. I understand how any vector could be written as the difference of $2$ non negative vectors with one of the vectors having all components the same.  However, I don't understand how to solve the linear program below:

\begin{align}
\min &\quad2x_1 + 3x_2 - x_3 + x_4\\
\mathrm{s.t.}&\quad x_1 + 2x_2 - x_3 - 5x_4 = 10\\
&\quad -2x_1 + 3x_3-2x_4 = 5\\
&\quad x_1\geqslant0
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

You replace the free variables $x_j$ by $x_j^+-x_j^- \ \ \forall \ \ j \in \{2,3,4\}$.

Therefore the objective function is

$2x_1 + 3(x_2^+-x_2^-) - x_3^++x_3^- + x_4^+-x_4^-$

Similar transformations for the constraints. The domain for the variables is $x_1,x_2^+,x_2^-,x_3^+,x_3^-,x_4^+,x_4^- \geq 0$.

Now you can apply an algorithm, for instance the simplex algorithm.

Comment: Thank you but someone edited my post so you were probably unable to see the image of the book. I get what you are saying and I can get a solution to that no problem however what I cant understand is the other way of doing it to reduce the amount of free variables. Any vector can be written as the difference of 2 non-negative vectors with one of the vectors having all components the same. let x2,x3,x4= (u-we) were w is a real number and u is an element Reals^k.  I just cant see to apply it to solve the problem.

Comment: @Eamonn Just eliminate $x_2,x_3$ or $x_4$, then the problem will be very easy.